# After upgrade to 5.50.4 the extension details not showing

Tags: extension, upgrade, missing, data

After the upgrade to 5.50.4, the extension details do not display for any of the extensions under Administer -> System Settings -> Extensions.
Here is the HTML that is produced:

```
<tr class="hiddenElement even" id="crm-extensions-details-authx" role="row" style="display: table-row;">
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

Visually, it looks like this:
[image: Extension Details Missing]

Comment: General things to try (if not already) would include: clearing caches, using browser Inspect tool to see if any errors listed under Console tab. Don't know your skill level so just ask if you need more explanations

Comment: Already tried everything: cleared cache, reset paths, nothing in JS console log. No errors thrown in server error logs. Nothing to give any feedback as to why this happens. It's as if it is normal to not display the extension info. That's why I submitted this to the forum. Other than debugging it, I thought others may have experienced the same issue...